# Read Firebase Database via HTTPS REST with error: 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: rest, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, vapor

My configuration Swift 3, Vapor framework for server and Xcode 8.1

I am trying to read the contents of my firebase db by making a call to Firebase using an access_token received from Oauth 2.0, but I get `error 301 Moved Permanently`. What is the correct path to use in the uri of the GET request?
I suppose here is my mistake.

```
drop.get("it") { request in
 var accesstoken = "ya2Qdkg.... and so on"
  let responseFirebase = try drop.client.get("https://fir-34c2e.firebaseio.com/data/Users",
 headers: ["Authorization":"Authorization: Bearer \(accesstoken)"], 
      query: [:])

   print("FirebaseResponse_is \(responseFirebase)")
     return "success"
}
```

[image]

Comment: To make a HTTP request to the Firebase REST API, your URL needs to end in `.json`. So `"https://fir-34c2e.firebaseio.com/data/Users.json"`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen             Your suggestion works, but now I get Permission denied when I try to read the db. I am trying to access the db using an access token I received from Google OAuth2.0 server. The request to OAuth was made with a service account. The rules in my **[database look like this](http://imgur.com/a/Ilavs)**